# struts2 session expired application scope

Tags: security, session, struts2, interceptor

My app uses struts2+spring+hibernate and I was doing some session-interceptor-login-authorisation system and its working alright, now that I try to implement the session expired part I'm running into problems:
first the session interceptor checks  for every request to see if a user is on session if not then  its redirected to the login page, otherwise its let through the action requested  .

- so if the user has just began the app the login page pops up
- if the session has timeout because of the  session-timeout property in web.xml its then redirected to a login page

Now I had a request that a session expired message be displayed.
So I decided to use the app scope and set some variables like UserLoggedIn 
and now back to the interceptor I can check for the user to be in session and if its null check the app scope for the variable UserLoggedIn so if founded then session is expired (sessionExpired.jsp) otherwise  login.jsp.
the problem is that whenever I close the browser and reopen it, the app scope its still there and UserLoggedIn variable with it so  lets say I want to start the browser and my app
 so the session interceptor its fired it doesn't find a user on session GReat!! but it found the UserLoggedIn variable which is telling that this is not a brand new start so the session expired message its pop up. I know its kind of confusing Im not sure if this is the right way to do this session expired thing; its my first try.

any advice, alternative methods, etc, will be really appreciated

pd: I know that there are better approaches into securing your app like spring security
    I devoted 2 days but failed and because of  the time factor Im cant keep trying whit it

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to move the session time out into the interceptor it self, that is every time the interceptor is used it will set a time value for the user if the time value is too great between invocations you will get redirected to the session timed out page. After all it is the session that is telling you that it is stale, so you should be able to avoid application level logic.

Comment: Thanks for answering, is there any special lib that I have to use for the servlet timeout or just an adhoc implementation and check if this value is greater than an x value when the interceptor fires again to set the timeot?

Comment: I'd go with the adhoc implementation you stated.  When the user signs in you stick some identifier for that user into the session then you could stick a timestamp value into the session or possibly into the DB (If you also have the DBA hat, why not).  On the upside if you did put data into the db you could easily make a cool who's signed in administration page and possibly include some usage metrics =) It would be useful for testing, and management loves "over the shoulder tools".